# Find the shortest distance of the curve $\frac{(x-3)^2}{4}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{9}=1$ from the origin

Tags: calculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, second-order-cone-programming

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185627

Referring to the methods mentioned in this answer, after trying the first method I got a term that looked like this:

$$\sqrt{14 + 5\sin^2{\theta} + 6\sin{\theta} + 12\cos{\theta}}$$

Which was rather difficult to find a minima of, algebraically.

Using a common method, i.e. the shortest distance of a point from a curve lies along its common normal line.

I ended up with an equation,
$$2 \sec{\theta} - 9 \csc{\theta} = 5$$

Which was again rather difficult to solve algebraically.

Can someone please help me solve the above equations, or solve the question with an alternate solution?

Comment: You did all that parametric math to get to $x=3+2cos\theta$ and $y=1+3sin\theta$?

Comment: This was my exact method to obtain the first expression:

$x=3+2cos{\theta}$ and $y = 1+3sin{\theta}$

Using the distance formula 

$$\sqrt{(3+2cos^2{theta})^2 + (1+3sin^2{\theta})^2}$$

$$ = \sqrt{9+4cos^2{\theta} + 12 cos{\theta} + 1 + 9sin^2{\theta} + 6sin{\theta}}$$
$$ = \sqrt{10 + 4cos^2{\theta} + 4sin^2{\theta} + 5sin^2{\theta} + 6sin{\theta} + 12 cos{\theta}}$$

$$=\sqrt{14 + 5sin^2{\theta} + 6sin{\theta} + 12cos{\theta}}$$


Also how can we say that for the minimum of $asin{\theta} + bcos{\theta} + c$

the entire function will attain a minima?

Comment: Well yes, you can try a calculus approach to minimize that function $f(\theta)$

Comment: (1/2) You can look at this as problem of minimizing $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ with constraint $g(x,y) = \frac{(x-3)^2}{4}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{9}-1 = 0$. This falls down onto territory of [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). Calculating gradients gives us system $\lambda(x-3) = 4x$, $\lambda(y-1) = 9y$ and eliminating $\lambda$ gives us $y = \frac{4x}{27-5x}$. Substituting that into the constraint $g(x,y) = 0$ will result in a quartic equation $25 x^4 - 420 x^3 + 2510 x^2 - 5940 x + 3969= 0$.

Comment: (2/2) There are two real solutions, $x_1≈1.0727$ and $x_2≈4.3306$, minimum being obtained for $x_1$. The distance from the origin is the square root of $f$ and is $d\approx 1.09091$. You can see that this works from the following [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%3D1.09091%5E2%2C+%28x-3%29%5E2%2F4%2B%28y-1%29%5E2%2F9+%3D1).

Comment: Thank you for this solution.

Comment: You are welcome. I wasn't sure if you'd be satisfied with this, but I can turn it into an answer.

Comment: Please refer to the graphical approach from my older post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801211/how-to-find-a-point-on-an-ellipse-whose-normal-intersects-a-point-outside-the-el/2801747#2801747).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will copy what I wrote in comments as an answer.

You can look at this as the problem of minimizing $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ with constraint $g(x,y) = \frac{(x-3)^2}{4}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{9}-1 = 0$. This falls down onto the territory of [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). Calculating gradients gives us $\nabla f(x,y) = (2x,2y)$ and $\nabla g(x,y) = \left(\frac 12(x-3), \frac 29(y-1)\right)$ which need to be colinear, so we get system
\begin{align}
\lambda(x-3) &= 4x\\
\lambda(y-1) &= 9y
\end{align} and eliminating $\lambda$ gives us $ y= \frac{4x}{27-5x}$. We can substitute that into the constraint $g(x,y) = 0$ which then simplifies to finding the roots of quartic $25 x^4 - 420 x^3 + 2510 x^2 - 5940 x + 3969$.

In theory, [quartics are solvable by radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation), so it's possible to obtain explicit solution, or you can use numerical methods, depending on what you are looking for. For example, you could use [Durand–Kerner method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method).

It turns out that we have two real solutions $x_1≈1.0727$, $x_2≈4.3306$, minimum being obtained by $x_1$, which you can verify from [bordered Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian). In this case, it boils down to calculating determinant of the bordered Hessian.

The value of $f(x,y)$ for $x = x_1$, $y = \frac{4x_1}{27-5x_1}$ is approximately $1.19001$, so the required distance is the square root of that, which is approximately $1.09088$.

You can convice yourself of the correctness of the result by looking at the following [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%3D1.09091%5E2%2C+%28x-3%29%5E2%2F4%2B%28y-1%29%5E2%2F9+%3D1).

Answer (score 2):

Back to your initial formulation, if your goal is to minimize with respect to $\theta$
$$L=\sqrt{14 + 5\sin^2(\theta) + 6\sin(\theta) + 12\cos(\theta)}$$, we need to find the zero of funtion
$$f(\theta)=\frac {d(L^2)}{d\theta}=5 \sin (2 \theta )+6 \cos (\theta )-12 \sin (\theta )=0$$ By inspection or graphing, we know that the solution is just above $\pi$.

Expanding as a series
$$f(\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1 {n!} \Bigg(\left(5\ 2^n+12\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi 
   n}{2}\right)-6 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)\Bigg)\,(\theta-\pi)^n$$

Truncating to some order and using power series reversion
$$\theta=\pi +\frac{3}{11}-\frac{27}{2662}+\frac{2817}{322102}-\frac{116397}{77948684}+\frac{39120327}{47158953820}+\cdots$$

Using only the above terms
$$\theta=\pi +\frac{6382174251}{23579476910}=3.41226$$ while the "exact" solution, as given by Newton method, is $3.41211$.

Using the approximate result then
$$L=1.09091077$$  while the "exact" solution is $1.09091065$

**Edit**

Even simpler : let $\theta=x+\pi$ which gives
$$g(x)=12 \sin (x)+5 \sin (2 x)-6 \cos (x)$$ and use the simple $[2,2]$ Padé approximant around $x=0$. This gives
$$g(x) \sim \frac {-6+\frac{12809 }{599}x+\frac{3569 }{1198} x^2} {1+\frac{123 }{1198}x+\frac{2731 }{7188}x^2 }$$ whose error is $\sim 2 x^5$.

So, at the price of a simple quadratic $$x \sim \frac{\sqrt{189724453}-12809}{3569} \quad \implies \quad \theta \sim 3.41199$$ which leads to
$$L_{\text{min}}=\color{red}{1.090910}72$$

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Could you please suggest me some resources to learn how to truncate these long Taylor expansions into a desired form.

Comment: @Grandmaster10. When I say *truncate*, I just mean using a few terms. For example, let $\theta=\pi+x$ and use the classical series for the since and cosine funtions up to a few terms.

Comment: By truncation I meant how did you express ${\theta}$ in terms of x in a linear format, that is the part I am facing some difficulty doing.

Comment: @Grandmaster10. Have a look at  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html  It is quite simple

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple idea coming from the fact that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ but so useful!

Answer (score 0):

The Eberly's method [ref](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2013.03.031) allows to efficiently project a point onto an ellipse.
After translation, we seek to project the point
$(U,V)=(-3,-1)$ onto the ellipse defined by
$\frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}=1$
where $a=2, b=3$.

We seek the ellipse point $(X,Y)$
where the normal is parallel to $(U-X,V-Y)$
This gives the two equations
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ccc}
U-X&=&t\frac{X}{a^2}\\
V-Y&=&t\frac{Y}{b^2}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
for some real $t$.
We find
$$
X(t)=\frac{a^2 U}{t+a^2},
Y(t)=\frac{b^2 V}{t+b^2}
$$
and we must solve (one) root of
$
P(t)=
\frac{X^2(t)}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2(t)}{b^2}-1
$.

The distance is finally
$d=
\sqrt{
\left[ U-X(t^*) \right]^2 +
\left[ V-Y(t^*)\right]^2}
$.

The numerical application gives
$t^*=2.226431983483, 
d=1.0909106524$.