# Shortest distance from point to a curve and Estimation of error of an incorrect approach

Tags: calculus, geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, curves

Today I wrote an answer to a question in regards to the topic of shortest distance between a point and a curve, more precisely an ellipse, [check here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4737207/1047493). Turns out the answer was incorrect, yet it was a close approximation, so it sparked an interesting discussion in the comments.

***TLDR*** 
My logic for finding a shortest distance from a specific point to an ellipse was to find tangent lines from that point to an ellipse and from there to find a line of symmetry of those two lines. That line of symmetry would intersect the ellipse and would be perpendicular to it, meaning that it should have given me the correct distance. Instead I got an estimate that was accurate up to the third decimal (might be because of rounding up because later when I checked with more decimal points it was incorrect at the second decimal).

For some backstory, I'm not sure how I got this idea. I've seen it used a few times with a circle (couldn't give you any examples right now) so I thought, using similar logic, that the same could be applied to an ellipse, but I guess I should of proved it beforehand.

Let's take a look at the logic I used. I will visualize things for easier understanding.
[image]

*In the following text, I'll bold possibly incorrect statements.* As you can see in the drawn out image, from point $O$ there are two tangent lines, let's denote them as $t_1, t_2$, to an ellipse that touch it at points $B$ and $C$, respectively. Then there is a line of symmetry between the lines $t_1$ and $t_2$, we'll call it $s$. Similarly to the circle the, we can say that $\pmb{\overline{OB}=\overline{OC}}$, **meaning $\pmb{\triangle{OBC}}$ is isosceles**. Now let's draw a line parallel to the one passing through $B$ and $C$ such that it passes through point $A$ and **it is tangent of an ellipse** (this is the most questionable statement). Now since all the lines of a triangle $\triangle OEF$ and $\triangle OBC$ are parallel it means they are similar, as such $\pmb{\triangle OEF}$ **is isosceles**. Because $s$ is a line of symmetry between two lines defined by two sides of $\triangle OEF$, it means that $s$ is line of symmetry of $\angle OEF$, **from the fact that it is isosceles triangle, we can conclude that** $\pmb{\overline{OA}}$ **is the height of $\pmb{\triangle OEF}$**. As such, we can say that it is **perpendicular to the tangent of an ellipse passing through** $\pmb A$.

You can see that all of the bolded points were directly related to one of two:
$1.$ $\overline{OB}=\overline{OC}$, 
$2.$ Line parallel to the one passing through $B$ and $C$ such that it passes through point $A$ is tangent of an ellipse.

My question is if you could prove or disprove both or any of these two statements (for example prove the correct one and disprove the incorrect one) which most likely led me to a mistake.

***Note***
*I know it is very likely that at least one of those statements is incorrect, so if you were to disprove them could you do like a general case, because I've already seen it on a specific example, I'm of course talking about the one in the original post I've answered to.*

Another thing I'd like to ask, in the comments user Ennar raised a good concern, basically asking about the error estimate of doing the calculation of the question the way I did it. Is there any general formula for that estimate that could be found?

***Another Note***
*I know this specific example used an ellipse, but it could of course be applied to any curve with the exception of circle because we know that shortest distance from point to a circle could be found with the mentioned method.*

***Edit***
Based on one of my comments here, user *mathlove* has given an answer. Essentially finding the angle $\angle AOA_1$, where $O$ and $A$ are like in the picture I've posted and $A_1$ is the point that is the real closest point on the curve (in this case an ellipse) to $O$. My idea was that function of error of my estimation can be represented as a function of that angle $\angle AOA_1$. After we find the angle how to do the rest of the job, how to relate it to the precentage error from the correct answer? After writing the comment about this idea for finding function for error I thought maybe it wasn't the best idea. Especially considering how you would already need to know the correct answer to find the error, but then there is no need in finding one if you already have the correct solution. 
That's just me thinking out loud. Any ideas and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: $OB=OC$ is false, in general.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Finding an error in the made assumption" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: @NDB doesn't mean much withouth proof.

Comment: @jjagmath changed it.

Comment: NDB explained the problem: the two tangents usually don't have the same length. As an easy to understand counterexample consider the ellipse defined by the equation $x^2+4y^2=4$. If $O=(2,1)$, then the two tangent are the vertical $x=2$ and the horizontal $y=1$, meeting the ellipse at the end points of the semiaxes $B=(0,1)$ and $C=(2,0)$. These are at distances $2$ and $1$ from $O$ respectively.

Comment: For a more general approach I would use the following, based on [the implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem). At an extremal point $A$ we, indeed, have that the tangent to the curve is perpendicular to the is perpendicular to the line segment $OA$. This is also equivalent to the technique of finding constrained extrema of a function (here  $|OA|^2$ with $A$ constrained to the curve). This does require that the curve is given implicitly as the zero locus of a function.

Comment: (cont'd) Of course, if you have a (useful) parametrization, $x=x(t)$, $y=y(t)$, of the curve, then you can use methods from single variable calculus, and find the extremal points of the function $f(t):=(x_O-x(t))^2+(y_O-y(t))^2.$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen in regards to your second comment, let's denote the point of intersection of line of symmetry and curve as $A$ and extremal point of the curve as $A_1$.  Would that mean that the error function could be represented in sume way as a function of $\angle{A_1OA}$?

Answer (score 1):

To disprove the first statement:

Take the tangents that are parallel to the long and short axes of the ellipse. They intersect to a point (O) that is not at equal distance to the contact points B and C of the tangents with the ellipse. So OB ≠ OC.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But what how to find a general formula for estimating error between real result and result that someone you'd get using (wrong) method I used? What are all the variables that would affect the estimation in such way?

Comment: @bb_823 Just some random thoughts here: Think of the ellipse as a tilted disc compared to the plan of observation, and think of the point as a line perpendicular to the plan. In this set-up, your reasoning should be correct if applied between the disc and the line in the plan of the disc. How is it affected by applying it in a plan perpendicular to the line? I would say it depends on how the line is tilted and shifted compared to the central axis of the disc, which is determined by the relative lengths of the long and short axes of the ellipse and the relative position of the point.

Comment: In the comments I've written the idea of writing this error estimation as a function of angle between line of symmetry(the one I mentioned) and the line defined by the given point and closest point on the curve to that point. But on second thought problem with that is you'd already need to know what the correct answer is, so I like your line of reasoning better, as the function for error estimation is solely defined by relatioship between axis of an ellipse and the point. Then again this means that this error estimate can't be generalized to all curves, at least not in such way.

Answer (score 1):

Take the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. It is bound by axis-aligned square that goes through $(-1;1),(1;1),(1;-1),(-1;-1)$ points.
Take one of those points, let's say $O = (-1;1)$ - upper left corner.
From your solution, $B = (0;1), C = (-1;0)$

Now we stretch the picture in x-direction. Circle becomes an ellipse $(Nx)^2 + y^2 = 1$.
The point $O$ becomes $(-N;1)$.
Tangent lines are parallel or perpendicular to the stretch, so they don't change. $B = (0;1), C = (-N;0)$

Already here you can see that $OB \ne OC$ by an arbitrary amount.

Real closest point would be within 1 unit from $O$, since $C$ is part of ellipse at that distance.
But as we increase $N$, $BC$ becomes more horizontal, so $A$ moves further and further away.

[Here's geogebra of roughly this situation](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/gjnhkssn)

Answer (score 1):

You said in a comment that

> let's denote the point of intersection of line of symmetry and curve as $A$ and extremal point of the curve as $A_1$. Would that mean that the error function could be represented in sume way as a function of $\angle{A_1OA}$ ?

Let us consider two tangent lines $OB,OC$ where $B,C$ are tangent points on the curve $\dfrac{(x-c)^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{(y-d)^2}{b^2}=1$ with $a>0$ and $b>0$.

First, let us find the slope $M_1$ of the line $OA$.

Letting $y=mx$, we get $\dfrac{(x-c)^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{(mx-d)^2}{b^2}=1$, i.e.
$$(b^2+a^2m^2)x^2-2(b^2c+a^2md)x+b^2c^2+a^2d^2-a^2b^2=0$$

Now, $D=0$ is equivalent to
$$4(b^2c+a^2md)^2-4(b^2+a^2m^2)(b^2c^2+a^2d^2-a^2b^2)=0$$
i.e.
$$(a^2-c^2)m^2+2cdm+b^2-d^2=0$$

If $a^2-c^2\not=0$, then letting $m_1,m_2$ be the roots, we have
$$m_1+m_2=-\frac{2cd}{a^2-c^2},\qquad m_1m_2=\frac{b^2-d^2}{a^2-c^2}$$

Therefore, the equation of the line $OA$ is given by one of
$$\frac{m_1x-y}{\sqrt{m_1^2+1}}=\pm\frac{m_2x-y}{\sqrt{m_2^2+1}}$$
So, $M_1$ is one of
$$\begin{align}&\frac{\pm m_2\sqrt{m_1^2+1}-m_1\sqrt{m_2^2+1}}{-\sqrt{m_2^2+1}\pm\sqrt{m_1^2+1}}
\\\\&=\frac{(\pm m_2\sqrt{m_1^2+1}-m_1\sqrt{m_2^2+1})(-\sqrt{m_2^2+1}\mp\sqrt{m_1^2+1})}{(-\sqrt{m_2^2+1}\pm\sqrt{m_1^2+1})(-\sqrt{m_2^2+1}\mp\sqrt{m_1^2+1})}
\\\\&=\frac{\mp\sqrt{(m_1^2+1)(m_2^2+1)}-1+m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}
\\\\&=\frac{\mp\sqrt{(\frac{b^2-d^2}{a^2-c^2})^2+(-\frac{2cd}{a^2-c^2})^2-2(\frac{b^2-d^2}{a^2-c^2})+1}-1+\frac{b^2-d^2}{a^2-c^2}}{-\frac{2cd}{a^2-c^2}}
\\\\&=\frac{\pm\sqrt{(a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2)^2+4c^2d^2}+a^2-c^2-b^2+d^2}{2cd}\end{align}$$
We get
$$M_1=\frac{\color{red}+\sqrt{(a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2)^2+4c^2d^2}+a^2-c^2-b^2+d^2}{2cd}$$
since $M_1$ has to satisfy $(a^2-c^2)M_1^2+2cdM_1+b^2-d^2\gt 0$.)

---

Next, let us consider the slope $M_2$ of the line $OA_1$.

Let us use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4737187/78967). Our curve is $\dfrac{(x-c)^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{(y-d)^2}{b^2}=1$, so we get the system $\begin{cases}2x=\frac{2(x-c)\lambda}{a^2}
\\2y=\frac{2(y-d)\lambda}{b^2}\end{cases}$, so eliminating $\lambda$ gives
$y=\dfrac{a^2dx}{(a^2-b^2)x+b^2c}$, so we finally get

$$(a-b)^2(a+b)^2x^4-2 c (a - b) (a + b) (a^2 - 2 b^2)x^3+(-a^6+ 2 a^4 b^2  + a^4 c^2- 6 a^2 b^2 c^2+ a^2 b^2 d^2 + 6 b^4 c^2 - a^2 b^4   )x^2-2 b^2 c (a^4 - a^2 b^2 - a^2 c^2 + a^2 d^2 + 2 b^2 c^2)x+b^2 c^2 (-a^2 b^2 + a^2 d^2 + b^2 c^2)=0\tag2$$

Let $X$ be the $x$-coordinate of $A_1$. Then, $X$ is a root of $(2)$.

Then, the slope of the line $OA_1$ is given by $M_2=\dfrac{a^2d}{(a^2-b^2)X+b^2c}$.

$\angle{A_1OA}$ can be represented as
$$\angle{A_1OA}=\arctan\bigg(\frac{M_1-M_2}{1+M_1M_2}\bigg)$$

---

**Example** : $a=3,b=4,c=2,d=5$

We get $M_1=\dfrac{7+\sqrt{149}}{10}$, and $(2)$ has two real roots $x\approx 0.7888, 2.6547$. The former is what we want, and so $M_2\approx 1.3596$.

So, we get $\color{red}{\angle{A_1OA}\approx 8.831^\circ}$.

[image]

Comment: Now the next step would be representing the error using this angle, seems like you've completed the hard part, but I'm still struggling to find how to relate this to the error between real result and the one gotten by my method. Also in the answer by Quark I suggested that this method of finding error might be flawed, because you would need to know the correct result before even finding the error. Then what would be the point of making estimates and estimations of error of those estimamtes if we already know  the correct result? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem can be reformulated as concurrent normals through a given point.**

- A central conic has $2$ to $4$ concurrent normals from a given point.
- A parabola has $1$ to $3$ concurrent normals from a given point.
- For a conic $S$ in general form

$$0=
\begin{pmatrix}
  x &  y  &  1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    a & h & g \\
    h & b & f \\
    g & f & c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\  y \\  1
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{1}$$

- Equation of tangent at $(X,Y)$ lying on $S$

$$0=
\begin{pmatrix}
  X &  Y  &  1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    a & h & g \\
    h & b & f \\
    g & f & c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\  y \\  1
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{2}$$

- Equation of normal at $(X,Y)$ lying on $S$

$$0=
\begin{pmatrix}
  X &  Y  &  1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    a & h \\
    h & b \\
    g & f
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  y-Y \\  X-x
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{3}$$

- If $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ are the feet (or pedals) of the concurrent normals from $A(x',y')$, then switching the roles of $(x,y)$ and $(X,Y)$ gives an Apollonian rectangular hyperbola

$$0=
\begin{pmatrix}
  x &  y  &  1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    a & h \\
    h & b \\
    g & f
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  y'-y \\  x-x'
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{4}$$

[image]

- The intersections of two conics are the required feet of the concurrent normals.
- The rectangular hyperbola also passes the centre of a central conic.
- Up to first order, a very rough approximate of the closest pedal is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  x' \\ y'
\end{pmatrix}-
\frac{
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x' & y' & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & h & g \\
    h & b & f \\
    g & f & c
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x' \\ y' \\ 1
  \end{pmatrix}
}{2
  \begin{Vmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      a & h & g \\
      h & b & f
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      x' \\ y' \\ 1
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{Vmatrix}^{\,2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & h & f \\
  h & b & g \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x' \\ y' \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

- For further interests, please refer to older posts of mine [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281470/complex-nos-in-ellipse) and [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801211/how-to-find-a-point-on-an-ellipse-whose-normal-intersects-a-point-outside-the-el/2801747#2801747).

> **Useful fact:**
>
> Equation of tangent for a conic $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ at the point $(x',y')$ is given by
>
> $$ax'x+h(y'x+x'y)+by'y+g(x+x')+f(y+y')+c=0$$

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm having problem understanding this. There are a lot of new terms I haven't seen.

Comment: @bb_823 It's a summary of my previous answers.  The presentation requires one to have solid background in coordinate geometry, linear algebra and calculus.  Anyways, please also refer to another links from the older posts mentioned.

Comment: @bb_823 By the way, your approach will fail when the given point is on the same side of the centres of curvature (e.g. interior of an ellipse).  See another answer of mine concerning **pole-and-polar** relation [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864782/common-point-between-ellipse-and-tangent-passing-through-external-point/2865098#2865098).

Answer (score -1):

As an extreme numerical counter example take the case of one thinnest allowable ellipse whose ends of major axis are situated at $(0,3), (5,12). $ Center is at $(2.5,4.5);~~ 2a= \sqrt{5^2+9^2},~ 2b=0; $

Tangent lengths  $(3, 13) $ are not equal.

Comment: "if you were to disprove them could you do like a general case, because I've already seen it on a specific example". Besides,  The Quark already gave a generalized counterexample in their answer, what I need now is "Another thing I'd like to ask, in the comments user Ennar raised a good concern, basically asking about the error estimate of doing the calculation of the question the way I did it. Is there any general formula for that estimate that could be found?"

Comment: It appears that for proving general cases that approach  is ok  but for counter examples one case would suffice.